# Upload multiple images for a single product in django

Tags: python, django, model

I have created some nice models in **models.py** for uploading multiple images in single products, for different products. The good thing it uses one image model for all products. Now i'm failing to create a perfect **forms.py**. May someone help me please.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey
from mptt.models import MPTTModel
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Form, TextInput, Textarea



def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    model = instance.album.model.__class__._meta
    name = model.verbose_name_plural.replace(' ', '_')
    return f'{name}/images/{filename}'

class ImageAlbum(models.Model):
    def default(self):
        return self.images.filter(default=True).first()

    def thumbnails(self):
        return self.images.filter(width__lt=100, length_lt=100)

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    width = models.FloatField(default=100)
    length = models.FloatField(default=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(ImageAlbum, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    album = models.OneToOneField(ImageAlbum, related_name='model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Vehicle(Product):
    STATUS = (
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
    )

    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    mileage = models.IntegerField() 
    ...
```

Comment: You should look into Django "formsets"

Comment: what are your expectations ? can you define your perfect form ?

Comment: in forms.py, i need to create a form for image album that will be integrated by any product form (eg Vehicle, Building). As you can see in models, i created model called Vehicle, I i would like to created more models like, Building, Computer, etc. Other models there in models.py are for handling image upload. I made them dynamic. I need to create a dynamic form also that will be integrated by any form that i will create for other models( Building, Computer, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "model" after album in `model = instance.album.model.__class__._meta`